# How to change sidebar div position to the top of content if window resized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I got two numbers of div tag, with `float left` and the `width 50%` like the following image :[image]
What i want my div tag position on the screen change like this if the window size changed: [image]

I know that the code must be written into media, for different screen sizes but i don't know what to do in order to change the position of these two DIV tags

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like this, when the width is smaller than 796px the sidebar will be over the content but note that in the html the `div.sidebar` should be before the `div.content`

```css
.sidebar{
  background:#4F6072;
}
.content{
  background:#4F9996;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .sidebar{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
  }
  .content{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">Page sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">Page content</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also doing this using Bootstrap.

So, You need not to write @media query for that

```
 You can check out link here:
https://jsfiddle.net/md93vpxj/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/md93vpxj/

Comment: You should at least add the relevant portion of your fiddle to the post so one can see your idea directly and not only after going to jsfiddle.net